# Are there any shorter works approaching the breadth of Durant's "The Story of Civilization"?

Tags: book

Is there a survey of human history that approaches the breadth of Durant's "The Story of Civilization" that is less than 11,000 pages (i.e. that wouldn't require a lifetime of study)? I'm not a historian, but I thoroughly enjoyed Durant's "The Lessons of History" and would like to read something similar that goes in more depth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for general purpose references are out of scope (See [ask] and [meta](meta.history.stackexchange.com)). This is still a debated subject, but until the debate is resolved, we should follow the established rules.  Amazon or goodreads will provide suggestions on what to read next. Good luck!

Comment: I see some contradiction between asking for the same breadth and asking for something substantially shorter.

Comment: @Greg: there is no contradiction: volume is a product of breadth and depth, so to speak. School kids manage to learn the whole breadth of Antiquity in a single year in 2-3 class meetings/week; those who are actually interested in Antiquity would spend 10x more time on it, and still feel they just scratched the surface.

Comment: H.G. Wells wrote "A Short History of the World" in the early 20th century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isaac Asimov's [Chronology of the World](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062700367), 700 pages.